# sqlexpress local database administrator password

Tags: .net, sql-server, installation, webmatrix

I'm trying to install some .Net eCommerce projects on my local machine (windows Vista) with Webmatrix. Some of them ask for a Database administrator username and password, but I have no idea what those are.

Can anybody help me on this. See image which is a screenshot of the installation process.

[image: Screenshot of installation process]

Comment: didn't web matrix give you these? it did when i used orchard.

Comment: nope, I was able to install Orchard just fine, I think that uses SQL compact and not Express

Comment: as part of the installation process of the projects I installed with Webmatrix, but I do not recall being asked to enter a password

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By Default the SQLEXPRESS installation uses Windows Authentication. in the management studio on the security-tab of the server properties you can select "SQL Server and Windows Authentication"
ONLY THEN The 'sa' account is accepted. You probably have to set/reset the password for this account if you can't remember you entered it.

Comment: I had to uninstall Management studio epxress 2005 and install 2008 (pff took forever to install) and then was able to change the password with the Management studio

Comment: I still wasn't able to log in with the sa account, then I tried to logon to the Manager studio with the sa account and it said it was disabled (huh?), I was able to enable it via the properties of the sa account and then the Status tab

Comment: you will need to log in to management studio using windows authentication first if SQL auth is not enabled

Answer (score 17):

In your client (SQL Server Management Studio) you have to:

1. change password for login user "sa"
2. enable login for user "sa"
3. ensure SQL Server authentication is enabled

### 1. change password for login user "sa"

Security > Logins > sa (right-click) > Properties > General > Password and Confirm password

### 2. enable login for user "sa"

Security > Logins > sa (right-click) > Properties > Status > Login, click in Enabled

### 3. ensure SQL Server authentication is enabled

Right click on server > Properties > Security > Server authentication, click in SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode

Comment: 4. You may need to restart the SQL Server service. Right Click on Server name > Restart.

Comment: Could it be that step 1 requires that the user that connected to the database has sufficient permissions to change the password of sa?
I got `Alter failed for Login 'sa'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)` and  `Cannot alter the login 'sa', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. 
(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15151)` See the question [sql server 2012: cannot alter the login sa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788853/)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and i performed the below steps to resolve the issue:

1. Open Sql Server Management Studio as Administartor
2. Login to  .\SQLEXPRESS using Windows Authentication
3. Go to Security Tab -- > Logins --> Change the "sa" password and Press Ok
4. Use the newly created Password in WebMatrix and you should be all Set.

Comment: I do not find a `Logins` tab after opening SSMS as administrator.

Comment: @Veverke It's more of a folder, not a tab. It's located in the Object Explorer window under the database connection

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL 2005 the Express edition is installed with windows authentication. In the configuration (management studio, connect to the server and choose database properties) you can activate sql internal authentification then (default deactivated, user sa without password).

So if you can't connect it you might have to activate it and set a password for the user sa then.